# How can I stop an activity until other activity is over?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have an activity where I start a new activity but I want to stop the previous activity until the new activity is over because otherwise I can't use the new data from the new activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's exactly what startActivityForResult is used for. Your activity is called back (onActivityResult) when invoked Activity posts results.

Comment: I thought that I should use startActivityForResult but I was not sure. Thank you a lot!